# Is it possible to deploy a NodeJs app in Vercel?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to deploy an API (made in Node) at Vercel (https://vercel.com, before Now) from the CLI. But when I deploy the app, I open the site and the result is just the files in the path directory, and not the app running. This is my `server.js`

```
    {
  "name": "subtitles-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "pre-deploy": "node deleteLastDeploy.js",
    "deploy": "npm run pre-deploy && now --public && now alias",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    //list of dependencies
  }
}
```

To see the full API: https://github.com/bitflix-official/subtitles-api

Answer (score 31):

#### Run  `yarn global add now@latest` to install the CLI

1. Create a `now.json` file and paste this

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{
    "src": "./server.js",
    "use": "@now/node-server"
  }],
  "routes": [{"handle": "filesystem"},
    {
      "src": "/.*",
      "dest": "server.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note**: Change `"src": "server.js",` && `"dest":"server.js"` to your server entry file.

2. Add it to `.gitignore`
3. Then run `now` in the CLI to deploy.

If you are deploying to production use `now --prod` command in the CLI to deploy

Here is an example server that I deployed: https://vercel-example-server.now.sh.

Comment: could you mention some tutorials on the new zeit 2.0 / vercel? i really need them.

Comment: @RahulVerma You can see this video https://youtu.be/ioea7mmOW8Y. This is an hour-long video, he will deploy in bunch of frontend frameworks.

Comment: Imho, this should be the accepted answer in this case.

Comment: I hosted a server in vercel , check this repo to know more https://github.com/vj-abishek/spotify-server#setup

Comment: I've hosted APIs in vercel with your method, but could you also serve up your front-end (eg; React) from your node.js files? From my experience, Vercel can't process it.

Answer (score 19):

I just deployed a node.js app(13-09-2022) after hearing that Heroku is no longer offering their free tier.

Edit: Still works as of (03-09-2023)

These are the steps I performed

1)make a vercel.json and add this

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

2)Go to your package.json and add the engine column

```
{
  "name": "api-make",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
```

3)don't forget to change the "start" in the script to your file name

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Now you are good to go
**Note:I I'm not sure why but I had my file named as app.js I was getting a 404 error I did change it to app.js everywhere still I'm not sure so I had to change it back to index.js**

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I also got rid of the 404 error after renaming "app.js" => "index.js" (and updating all references to it).

Comment: FYI Heroku isn't shutting down - they just stopped offering their free tier.

Comment: You right, for some reason renaming my `server.js` which was my initial entry file, to `index.js` and all its references solved my 404 issue.

Answer (score 13):

For the time being, with Vercel it's not possible to have a server-run web app that relies on Node.

> [Vercel](https://github.com/zeit/now/tree/master/examples#what-is-vercel) is a cloud platform for **static frontends** and serverless functions.

In order to deploy a node api with Vercel you would need to use their [serverless functions](https://vercel.com/docs/v2/serverless-functions/supported-languages#node.js).

Comment: In addition to the default Node.js request/response objects, Vercel offers [Node.js helpers](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/node-js/node-js-request-and-response-objects) that are similar to what you might use with Express.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at https://github.com/Chuloo/now-express repository for their serverless boilerplate code

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ExpressJS, if you try to deploy your app to Vercel  according to their docs, you'll have only one single serverless function /api. But this article helped me deploy separate function for each route in my Express app. So you might e able to deploy a NodeJS app as well. I found it easy to do.

See this you can deploy NodeJS App by splitting routes into functions.

https://antappan.medium.com/deploy-express-project-with-multiple-routes-to-vercel-as-multiple-serverless-functions-567c6ea9eb36

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.