# Cannot deploy new API routes using Vercel (Zeit Now)

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I've been developing an Node.js/Express.js API and running it on localhost. I set up the API to be hosted on Zeit Now (currently Vercel).

When I first started the API, I deployed 2 routes to Zeit Now using the "Now" command. Those routes worked fine when I accessed them. Now about half a year later, I tried to deploy a bunch of additional routes view the "Now" command, but when I go to access the new routes on the deployed version, they return a 404 status.

The new routes are in now.json.

This is the format of this file:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [{ "src": "index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/login",
            "dest": "/index.js",
            "methods": ["POST"]
        },
        {
            "src": "/exampleget",
            "dest": "/index.js",
            "methods": ["GET"]
        },
        {
            "src": "/examplepost",
            "dest": "/index.js",
            "methods": ["POST"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The route that is not working is /login. I've also tried with other routes not shown in this file. They didn't work either.

Can I no longer deploy routes this way after the transition from Zeit to Vercel?

Comment: check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61862836/10239185]

Comment: @BesufkadMenji Based on that answer, I would need follow the steps here https://vercel.com/guides/migrate-to-vercel#moving-to-vercel-and-serverless. But the first answer to that question says that my configuration should be correct